# Free space optical communication simulation in matlab

Tags: communication, optical-communication, optical-fiber, x-ray-communication

I want to do availability assessment of a free space optical link with weather data. However, available weather data are not sufficient and are not in needed standard. Hence, I manipulated with some logic to meet up to the standard, that obviously introduced some errors and such.
Now I want to varify if the generated availability from manipulated weather data is accurate or not through simulation of optical link.
I am lost, as how to do it in matlab. In optisystem, there is FSO channel available, however, how do I use it to represent every minutes of whole year. since each minute will have different weather parameter value, turbulence value (however small in variation).

Comment: This seems like a purely programming question, and not anything about space exploration.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how the weather data is formatted, I would say to use a cell array with the index being the minute of the year.

```
for i = 1:minutesInAYear

    data{i} = getWeatherDataForMinute(i);

end
```

In addition, this paper may be of use to you, if you have simulink: https://www.ijariit.com/manuscripts/v3i4/V3I4-1224.pdf